# rails file location

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use jquery dataTables with TableTools.  It needs access to a swf file.
Where should I put the swf folder?  And what would the path look like?

example code

```
$('#dataTable').dataTable({
    "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "oTableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "/public/swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf"
    }
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work if you put the file as:  `/public/swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf` ?   if so, please check your access permission to this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put the `.swf` file on the `public` folder, however, when linking to it, you'll remove the `public` path and access it as if it were on your application's root.

So you'll write something like this:

```
$('#dataTable').dataTable({
    "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "oTableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf"
    }
});
```

Comment: for the less observant among us (like me) that copied this verbatim - there is a type in the name CVS instead of CSV...

Comment: actually, the typo is in the original question, I just copied over :)